# Deploying Jenkin's Master-Slave without SSH acess in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, ssh, amazon-ec2, master-slave

Is there a way I can setup Jenkins in Master-Slave configuration where the master slave has no permissions to SSH into the slaves? I can grant pretty much any other type of access.

Im asking in context to AWS, I would rather not store SSH key-pairs on the master's mounted EBS, even if encrypted, for 'security reasons'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way I can setup Jenkins in Master-Slave configuration where the master slave has no permissions to SSH into the slaves? I can grant pretty much any other type of access.

Initially, to install packages on all 3 servers, you will need to SSH into all servers and do the setup. Configure and put files over the master and slaves. 
You can follow something like this: https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/setting-up-jenkins-master-slave-architecture-shashikant-jagtap

I understand your concern, but that is a bare minimal you need to do. If you're concerned, you can change SSH port for your servers while keeping the key on the master and for that you can follow this:
https://in.godaddy.com/help/changing-the-ssh-port-for-your-linux-server-7306

Let me know if you need anything else.